# Serverless Framework, setting up rest api lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I wanted to make a lambda available at `dev-api.example.com/auth/*`.
The lambda will act like an auth service. So it will have urls like

- dev-api.example.com/auth/register
- dev-api.example.com/auth/login
- and more ...

Like wise more lambdas will be hooked to single `ApiGateway`.

With that design decision, I wrote following `serverless.yml` file.

```
// serverless.yml
...
custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: dev-api.example.com
    stage: prod
    basePath: ''
...

functions:
  auth:
    handler: src/index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /{auth+}
```

It does not seem to work. Whenever I visit `dev-api.example.com/auth/register` it returns `Not Found` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @hoangdv , your suggestion almost fixed the problem.

The issue was with `path`. It should have been `path: auth/{proxy+}` instead of `path: /{auth+}`

```
functions:
  auth:
    handler: src/index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: auth/{proxy+}
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS API Gateway only accepts `{proxy+}` syntax ([Link](https://aws.amazon.com/vi/blogs/aws/api-gateway-update-new-features-simplify-api-development/)), then I think serverless fw just support `{proxy+}` and `{any+}`.

If you want to just create a function to handle 2 api endpoint, in this case, the endpoints are

`POST /auth/register` (I think so)

`POST /auth/login`

Then you have setting in serverless.yml like

```
...
functions:
  auth:
    handler: src/index.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: auth/{any+} # this matches any path, the token 'any' doesn't mean anything special
...
```